# Trying to save audio to mp3, saving to wav instead

Tags: python, mp3, streamlit, bytesio, gtts

I am making a project for class and the chatbot I have waves the file to .wav instead of .mp3 like the project requires. I do not know how to save it to mp3.`

```
import streamlit as st
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
from bokeh.models import CustomJS

from streamlit_bokeh_events import streamlit_bokeh_events

from gtts import gTTS
from io import BytesIO
import openai
import uuid
from pydub.playback import play
from pydub import AudioSegment

openai.api_key = 'my_key'

if 'prompts' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['prompts'] = [{"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant. Answer as concisely as possible with a little humor expression."}]

def generate_response(prompt):

    st.session_state['prompts'].append({"role": "user", "content":prompt})
    completion=openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages = st.session_state['prompts']
    )
    
    message=completion.choices[0].message.content
    return message

sound = BytesIO()

placeholder = st.container()

placeholder.title("Group 4 Voice ChatBot")
stt_button = Button(label='SPEAK', button_type='success', margin = (5, 5, 5, 5), width=200)


stt_button.js_on_event("button_click", CustomJS(code="""
    var value = "";
    var rand = 0;
    var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    recognition.continuous = false;
    recognition.interimResults = true;
    recognition.lang = 'en';

    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("GET_ONREC", {detail: 'start'}));
    
    recognition.onspeechstart = function () {
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("GET_ONREC", {detail: 'running'}));
    }
    recognition.onsoundend = function () {
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("GET_ONREC", {detail: 'stop'}));
    }
    recognition.onresult = function (e) {
        var value2 = "";
        for (var i = e.resultIndex; i < e.results.length; ++i) {
            if (e.results[i].isFinal) {
                value += e.results[i][0].transcript;
                rand = Math.random();
                
            } else {
                value2 += e.results[i][0].transcript;
            }
        }
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("GET_TEXT", {detail: {t:value, s:rand}}));
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("GET_INTRM", {detail: value2}));

    }
    recognition.onerror = function(e) {
        document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("GET_ONREC", {detail: 'stop'}));
    }
    recognition.start();
    """))

result = streamlit_bokeh_events(
    bokeh_plot = stt_button,
    events="GET_TEXT,GET_ONREC,GET_INTRM",
    key="listen",
    refresh_on_update=False,
    override_height=75,
    debounce_time=0)

tr = st.empty()

if 'input' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['input'] = dict(text='', session=0)

tr.text_area("**Your input**", value=st.session_state['input']['text'])

if result:
    if "GET_TEXT" in result:
        if result.get("GET_TEXT")["t"] != '' and result.get("GET_TEXT")["s"] != st.session_state['input']['session'] :
            st.session_state['input']['text'] = result.get("GET_TEXT")["t"]
            tr.text_area("**Your input**", value=st.session_state['input']['text'])
            st.session_state['input']['session'] = result.get("GET_TEXT")["s"]

    if "GET_INTRM" in result:
        if result.get("GET_INTRM") != '':
            tr.text_area("**Your input**", value=st.session_state['input']['text']+' '+result.get("GET_INTRM"))

    if "GET_ONREC" in result:
        if result.get("GET_ONREC") == 'start':
            placeholder.title("You can speak now!")
            st.session_state['input']['text'] = ''
        elif result.get("GET_ONREC") == 'running':
            placeholder.title("Transcribing")
        elif result.get("GET_ONREC") == 'stop':
            placeholder.title("Click Again To Ask Another Question")
            if st.session_state['input']['text'] != '':
                input = st.session_state['input']['text']
                output = generate_response(input)
                st.write("**ChatBot:**")
                st.write(output)
                st.session_state['input']['text'] = ''
#conda activate voice_recognition_software
                tts = gTTS(output, lang='en', tld='com')
                tts.write_to_fp(sound)
               #filename =  f"SpeechFile_{str(uuid.uuid4())}.mp3"
                st.audio(sound, format="audio/mp3")

                st.session_state['prompts'].append({"role": "user", "content":input})
                st.session_state['prompts'].append({"role": "assistant", "content":output})
```

`

I have tried both exporting from the bytes (aka "sound" in the code) and also changing the format of the st.audio (st.audio(sound, format="audio/mp3"), towards the end) it now just saves it to an empty file type (just .). Maybe the streamlit format is not correct, idk. The documentation is terrible on this subject

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please consider *never* to include your credentials in your post.   Please now regenerate your openai api key.